# Javascript XMLHttpRequest Login Promp

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, safari-extension

I am new to javascript and wrote a simple extension to parse the gmail atom feed and display the number of unread emails.

My problem is if for some reason you're not logged into your google account, the extension attempts to check the feed and Safari will display a login box like this.

[alt text http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/743/loginhd.png](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/743/loginhd.png)

And since I check every 10 seconds these prompts stack up and hijack the browser to the point where you can't go login. Also loggin via this prompt seems to do nothing.

Is there anyway to ignore failed attempts to read the feed? My request looks like this:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = checkForNewMessagesCallBack;
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Can you show the URL you are fetching and especially, what you are doing in the callback?

Comment: Sure. I'm checking mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom (which I got from Google's own docs). And then in the handler I just check the <totalcount> for the number of unread emails.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see it as a failed attempt so you can ignore it .. more like in progress and you are asked for info so that it can complete..

If this is for personal use you could use the https://username:password@URL 
The security risks of that method are of course obvious ..